# X.org does not start after 15.10 to 16.04 upgrade

Tags: xorg, kubuntu, crash

I upgraded Kubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04 today using the official upgrade process. The upgrade was smooth: no errors at any point during the process.

However, after rebooting, X.org fails to start up. The screen keeps "flashing" between trying to start xorg and failing (when it fails, I get thrown back to vt1). This keeps happening forever.

Here's the `Xorg.0.log` I pulled using a livecd: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15987227/. I see some segfaults in there, but I'm not sure how to read or analyse them.

My system is a Sony Vaio laptop with an intel and nvidia card (optimus setup). Currently, nvidia proprietary drivers are installed for occasional gaming. I'll update the post with lspci output shortly.

What I've tried till now:

- deleting `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` so that it can be regenerated
- changing the active screen in `xorg.conf` to `intel` and marking `nvidia` as `Inactive`
- removing all unnecessary config files from `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`

Nothing has worked, and I'm still stuck in an xorg crash loop.

Edit: Some more system info:

- `lspci -vvv` from livecd: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15987712/
- Default `xorg.conf` that's generated: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15987762/

  - this is where I had switched out `nvidia` and `intel` in `ServerLayout` section

Comment: Interestingly, when I did a purge removal of `nvidia-*` and `bumblebee-*` packages, the system booted up fine.

Comment: I can confirm this, It's happening to me as well. I just upgraded my laptop from 15.10 to 16.04 and the Kubuntu cannot show the login screen, all I see is black screen. I do have bumblebee and nvidia drivers installed, but didn't try to remove them. I'm sick of doing that every time I upgrade the major version.

Comment: @Kodeart, after some poking around, I learnt that bumblebee is not supported any more. It's not been updated in 3 years (anecdotal, haven't verified myself). Installing `nvidia-361` and `nvidia-prime`, and then using `nvidia-settings` to disable the nvidia card did the job for me. 

You might notice KDE doesn't have any desktop/window effects after doing that. To fix it, you need to go into system settings -> Display/Monitor -> Compositor and switch the rendering backend to OpenGL 3.1.

Comment: Had the same problem and applying this  http://askubuntu.com/a/761379/536172  answer did the trick.

Comment: @NikaBoss, that solution does not mention nvidia or bumblebee at all. I don't think it's related.