# Kubuntu doesn't work after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: boot, graphics, kubuntu

I have a new System76 Lemur Laptop.  It worked fine for a week.  I installed Kubuntu, it worked fine.  Then I upgraded to Kubuntu 16.04 LTS and the system doesn't boot fully anymore.  The Kubuntu logo flashes but then never displays the login UI, I just see black.  I can get a TTY by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> key.  I can run startx -- :1 from the TTY to get a bare bones graphical interface.

How can I get a usable graphical interface?

Comment: It didn't work after the first long tty, then I rebooted holding down shift and chose the latest os recovery; fixed broken pkgs and rebooted. It worked!

Comment: Same here. I start to hate K/Ubuntu! After every update/upgrade something essential is broken and the user is left with a blinking cursor... These are the moments when I regret to have switched to free and open (but crappy and broken) software :(

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
```

and selecting sddm worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me. I guess @Enkouyami's answer is a bit more hard-core approach, if above fails.

Comment: Take care: in my case this messed up my whole system! Needed to start the rescue console ... -1

Answer (score 5):

Run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop plasma-desktop plasma-desktop-data sddm xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-intel && sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
```

The 1st part will reinstall kubuntu's KDE plasma, the X11 display server, the sddm display manager, and the intel video driver; the next will allow you to set it as the default display manager. If some of those packages aren't installed, it will attempt to install them.

Logs are located at /var/log. Look for the log for Xorg and sddm.

Comment: Ok @DavidFoerster, I have clarified my position.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work.  I still see the same problems.  Is there some debug log that I should look at that might offer some clues?

Comment: @rrenaud Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall sddm; sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm` to reinstall & configure the sddm display manager. 
Logs are located at `/var/log/` and look for the ones for sddm and Xorg.

Comment: Also, could you make a bug report using `ubuntu-bug xorg`? You will probably get a lot more help than you could from askubuntu.

Comment: Reconfigure of sddm without reinstall worked for me.

Comment: I think he should try to reconfigure first  dpkg-reconfigure sddm

Answer (score 1):

Note - This message only aims at proprietary nvidia drivers users. I'm not sure if your laptops has one, but it may help for other people that were in the same situation. :

I just encountered a similar issue after updating my Kubuntu 16.04 setup (it already worked fine with it). Messing around KDE packages didn't help. However I noticed that Plasma was actually working but I didn't get any real visual feedback (right click worked as if plasma was properly started). I could start in a konsole using alt+f2 and blindly launching it. Manually restarting KWin (`kwin_x11 --replace`) showed me that compositing got disabled because of the lack of GLX extension in the X server. It was confirmed by glxgears not willing to start.

So I dropped in a TTY, logged in, `sudo service lightdm stop` (note : the default DM under Kubuntu is sddm so it most likely would be `sudo service sddm stop`), reinstalled the nvidia drivers, rebooted and it was back working.

I wonder if it was just about the X.org config (so try messing around `nvidia-xconfig` first) that got replaced or if the upgrade nuked up some GLX libraries.

Hopefully this will help you and some others going by!

Comment: The system76 lemur laptops use Intel integrated graphics.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem. I held the shift key down during boot and got to a menu where I chose "advanced options," then selected "upstart." At least I can do my office work now. Unknown how to make systemd, the new type of booting up, function.