# Kubuntu KDE desktop won't load because it cannot connect to X server

Tags: boot, kubuntu, kde, xserver

When I boot Kubuntu, it just starts a CLI instead of booting the desktop environment.

When I try `kstart` or `plasmashell` or `startkde`, it fails with the message "cannot connect to X server :0.0".

The problem is the same with or without `sudo`. (e.g. `kstart` and `sudo kstart`)

`echo $DISPLAY` outputs `:0.0`

PS:

- Reading [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111831/cannot-connect-to-x-server-0-0-as-superuser) on a different but related problem makes me think XAUTHORITY might be missing or malformed, but I'm not sure how to fix that. `echo $XAUTHORITY` returns nothing, just a blank.)
- Tried reinstalling `xorg`, `xauth`, `xserver-xorg`, and `xserver-xorg-core`. No change in the problem.
- [This](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=107170&p=247557#p247557) might also be relevant - kwin causing x to crash during boot.
- Trying to set DISPLAY as advised [here](http://nowardev.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/startkde-display-is-not-set-or-cannot-connect-to-the-x-server/) produced an error where it said that locking the authority file timed out. I tried [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/timeout-in-locking-authority-file-home-username-xauthority) solution, and although it got rid of that error message about locking the authority file, things still can't connect to X server.
- I guess another possibility is that the setting `DISPLAY=:0` is different from what those packages are looking for when they try to start. How can I tell what display number they're seeking?

Comment: did you try to reconfigure the display manger with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm`? take a look at this  [question](http://askubuntu.com/q/761358/458410) and [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/761379/458410)

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I had no progress in 6 hours of trying, and your short comment nailed it. Now to fix the other four things wrong with my boot process....

Comment: What else is wrong ? what works and what still doesn't ? I other issues are not related to this one, you should open another question. If that specific problem is solved, I'll post an answer that you can accept if it fix your issue and satisfy all you asked.